# Letters as footnote symbols on titlepage

Tags: footnotes, titles

I'm trying to format paper so that one the title page I can use 'a'as my symbol for footnote by the author's name. I tried to use the \renewcommand 
{\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{a} but that only changes the top symbol, not the bottom. This is my code:

```
\begin{document}  

\begin{titlepage}

\title{My paper}

\author{
{\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{a}
Me\footnote{info} }}

\maketitle

\end{titlepage}
```

when I compile this, I get the 'a' as the superscript, but at the bottom of the page I just get an '*'. Any idea why this keeps happening?

Comment: Your `\renewcommand` occurs inside at least two groups: one brought about by LaTeX itself when it typesets the author, and the other explicitly specified by you.  **Untested:** Try moving the `\renewcoomand` out of the `\author` declaration, but still inside the `titlepage` environment.  And, please, provide a minimal *compilable* example.

Comment: First, the correct command would be `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}. But second, the footnote itself will nevertheless be set with footnote symbols, because of the groups (see @GuM s comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside author is supposed to be an environment.. and outside it changes to it's default. So you have to give the command inside and outside
the title environment. (For this reason I defined '\myalph' command to mke
your document clear.) . Also even with the command inside and outside the author environment you need a trick because footnote command asks for the default footnotemark from the author environment. The trick is to give the footnotemark inside author and type it later using footnotetext.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\newcommand{\myalphfoot}
{
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
}
\begin{document}  

\begin{titlepage}

\title{My paper \footnote{test}}
\myalphfoot

\author{
\myalphfoot
Me\footnotemark[1] }

\footnotetext[1]{info}
\maketitle

\end{titlepage}


test\footnote{test2}

\end{document}
```